# Failed to open for writing:java to filenotfoundException faield:EACCES(permission denied)

Tags: javascript, filenotfoundexception, permission-denied, openfiledialog, file-access

FileNotFoundException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)Failed to open for writing:java to filenotfoundException faield:EACCES(permission denied)

FileNotFoundException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

In emulator (i use genymotion) it works fine, but when I run it on a real device (my phone is ASUS ZenFone Laser 5.0) throws a filenotfoundexception java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/cam20160926_075819.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) imgBitmap = ...

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your code. The error seems to indicate that you're trying to read/write into a file called `cam20160926_075819.jpg`. Does it exist on your phone? Is it hardcoded? Are you creating it as you go (for example, saving the output of your camera). Also - is your question related to Javascript or to Java? They are not the same.